# Deploying My App in Appstore With a Different Country

Tags: ios, app-store

Is it possible to deploy my app in appstore to a different country? for example , I got an apple Dev account in Indonesia , and I want to deploy my app Specifically for Australia. Currently my app is deployed in Indonesia , but I want it to ddeploy it Specifically for Australis , so In summary it would be 2 apps ( 1 in indo and 1 in australia ) but my account is bound in Indonesia.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Absolutely!

1. Go to your app under the "My Apps" section in iTunesConnect.

[image]

2. Select the "App Store" section for your app

[image]

3. "Pricing and Availability"

   [image]
4. Under "Availability" make sure "All territories selected" is selected.
   [image]
5. Click on the "Edit" button next to "All territories selected"
6. Select / Deselect the territories you want.

[image]

Comment: Thanks For this mate :)

Answer (score 0):

I think I already found the answer here and Yes it it possible:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/OCvkA.png